# Dictionary in jinja and flask to retrieve JPG/PNG image from base64 format

Tags: html, python-3.x, api, flask, jinja2

I want to display image in HTML page from the base64n string using flask and jinja template.

```
image_64 = base64.encodestring(image_read).decode("ascii")

output = {"username":username, "email": email, "Base64 Image": image_64}
return render_template('display.html', result = output)
```

I want to display dictionary value as image if the key is "Base64 Image". else display only the values.

what I tried is:

```
{% for key, value in result.items() %}

    <p> {{ key }} </p> 

    {% if result['Base64 Image'] != "" %}  

        <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{ value }}" alt="my_image"  id="img"/> </img><br>
        
    {% else %}

        <p> {{ value }} </p><br>

    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try to save the image in a dir and load the image in your desired format.

to save image you can try:

```py
@app.route('/api/scaning', methods=['GET'])
def scan_qr():
    img = request.files['img']
   
    ## save image
    img .save("temp_dir/"+img.filename)

    ## load Image
    img = cv2.imread(f"temp_dir/{img.filename}")

    return_value = MyModel.det_qr(img)
    return return_value
```